# How do I use addEventListener resize with useEffect to replace existing values from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, window-resize

I have a problem where I cannot replace the existing values of an array on window resize event. It just keeps adding values one after another.

I want to make it so that every time I resize the window the SetStart State's existing values are replaced with the new ones.

```
useEffect(() => {

      const hour = [...hourRef.current.children]
      const parentPos = parentWidthRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const hourWidth = Math.round(hour[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
    
    shifts.forEach((shift: any, shiftIndex: any) => {
      
      const childPosStart = hour.find((h, i) => h.getAttribute('data-id') == parseInt(shift.from.slice(0, 2))).getBoundingClientRect()
      
      const childPosEnd = hour.find((h, i) => h.getAttribute('data-id') == parseInt(shift.to.slice(0, 2))).getBoundingClientRect()

      **window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        setStart((start: any) => [...start, Math.round((childPosStart.left - parentPos.left) + ((parseInt(shift.from.slice(3, 5)) * hourWidth) / 60))])
      })**

        setStart((start: any) => [...start, Math.round((childPosStart.left - parentPos.left) + ((parseInt(shift.from.slice(3, 5)) * hourWidth) / 60))])

        setEnd((end: any) => [...end, Math.round((childPosEnd.left - parentPos.left) + ((parseInt(shift.to.slice(3, 5)) * hourWidth) / 60))])
      })

    
    return () => {
      setStart([])
      setEnd([])
    }
      
  }, [shifts])
```

Comment: So why do you add instead of replacing? Remove `...start` etc.

Comment: I tried it already but it inserts only one value in the array

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: No, so on the initial render shifts are being looped through and on every shift, a value is being added to setStart. What I need is on window resizing these values to be changed.

Comment: but you're adding a window listener in a `forEach` (so many window listeners for the same event) and never cleaning any of them up. Add and manage the removal of the listener once on mount in its own useEffect and delegate for each shift.

Comment: Excuse me for the dumb question, but how do I then get each shift.from when I'm not in a foreach anymore?

Comment: You've got things the other way around. Your for each should be inside the listener

Comment: Fixed it finally! thanks guys